# Htaccess on Forwarding http to https plus forcing www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I use the following code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^(index(\.php)?)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this work well for https when i add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^(index(\.php)?)?$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to force www infront it works only to force www infront but does not forward http to https.

any help on this

Answer (score 0):

To enforce `www` and `htpp->https` in same rule use an `OR` between 2 conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

3rd `RewriteCond` is for capturing value of domain after `www.`

Comment: its forwading index to https, i want index to be http

Comment: its work for www.website.com/index.php but since home page is index.php it forward to httpswww.website.com. instead of httpwww.website.com

Comment: That cannot happen as both rules have hardcoded `www.` in target URL. Make sure these 2 rules are top and you don't have any other rule while testing this **after clearing browser cache**